# Jquery datepicker in django not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker

I went through almost every question in this feed( I like to think so). But my jquery datepicker is not working. I dont know its been a while since im trying to make it happen and so i went through maximum tutorials and everything seems just fine with my code. Heres my code

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datePicker" readonly="true">
```

and my jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Do i need to include other script sources too?? This is all i have done and i dont know what went wrong. Somebodys gotta help me..

Comment: Working for me here : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/185/ . Did you included jquery-ui js and css files similar to that in fiddle?

Comment: This seems good to me. As you are using web url for js files, check if  it is getting downloaded properly in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

add the `jquery-ui css` in your link.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css

Answer (score 0):

And you should the delete  readonly="true" of input.
`<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datePicker">`